# ベクトルで表せる能力値を持ったキャラクター(個体)たちのうち、上位互換が存在しないものたちを選びたい

Tags: アルゴリズム, 計算量

たとえば、 RPG のキャラクターは、いろいろな能力値をもっています。(体力・素早さ・etc...)

つまりは、それぞれのキャラクター能力は、ベクトルで表せる、と表現できます。

```
# 例えば、 pandas を用いてキャラクター能力値を表現する
chara1 = pd.Series({'power': 1, 'speed': 2, 'magic': 3})
chara2 = pd.Series({'power': 2, 'speed': 1, 'magic': 2})
```

今、キャラクター A とキャラクター B がいたとき、もし、 A の能力値がすべて B のそれと同等かそれ以上である場合、キャラクター A はキャラクター B の上位互換であるとします。

#### 質問

キャラクターが N 体いたときに、上位互換が存在しないキャラクターの集合を求めたいです。どのように計算するのが効率的ですか？

(数学的な言い換え) ベクトル値の集合に対して、その上下関係を、「すべての要素について同等かそれ以上であって、かつ、少なくとも一つの要素が上回っている場合、そのベクトル値は、比較対象より上位であるとする」と定義した半順序集合に対して、その極大集合を効率的に求める方法は何でしょうか？

Comment: 全てのキャラクタの対について、上位互換かどうか

Comment: 総当たりで計算するしかないので、万能な『効率的』計算方法は存在しないはず。

Comment: ベクトルの次元よりNが十分大きければ、kd木使うだけでも総当たりよりはマシになりませんか